# Theano error while fitting a PyMC3 model in parallel - No module named 'tmpttugnbtl'

Tags: python, theano, pymc3

I'm fitting an identical `PyMC3` model to different datasets in parallel using `joblib` and the `multiprocessing` module and I'm running into a strange error.

Although the model fits fine for the vast majority of the datasets, it fails for a random subset, here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 567, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "fit_ogle3_2002.py", line 80, in fit_event
    pspl_model, alert_time  = initialize_model(event)
  File "/gpfs1/home/fb90/hierarchical/fit_albrow/model.py", line 88, in initialize_model
    mean = f*F_base*mag + (1 - f)*F_base
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/var.py", line 155, in __mul__
    return theano.tensor.mul(self, other)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 670, in __call__
    no_recycling=[])
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 955, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 858, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1217, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1157, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1624, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1148, in module_from_key
    module = self._get_from_key(key)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1047, in _get_from_key
    return self._get_module(name)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 720, in _get_module
    self.module_from_name[name] = dlimport(name)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 317, in dlimport
    rval = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, [module_name])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tmpttugnbtl'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fit_ogle3_2002.py", line 153, in <module>
    result = Parallel(n_jobs)(delayed(fit_event)(directory) for directory in dirs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 934, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tmpttugnbtl'
```

What exactly is `No module named 'tmpttugnbtl'` supposed to mean :S?

I'm using version `3.7` of PyMC3 and version `1.0.4` of Theano. The code is paralellized using the following lines

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

n_jobs = 32
result = Parallel(n_jobs)(delayed(fit_event)(directory) for directory in dirs)
```